Can't send notification to a specified user in websocket (STOMP)
`I ham developing a full stack application using react js and springboot i have enabled websockets using STOMP and Sockjs, and i have enabled spring security.
`type here`

i have a feature of sending friend request to another person and i have to send a notification to the user like you have received a notification, but i can't send the notification message to the user.
sending realtime notification or update is not working for me.
this is my configuration file
@Configuration @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer { your text`
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
config.enableSimpleBroker("/public","/topic","/queue");
config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
}
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
            .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .withSockJS();
}

}
this is my controller function
@PostMapping("/send-request/{from}")
public ResponseEntity<String> sendRequest(@PathVariable("from")String from, @RequestParam("to")String toPerson) {

    ResponseEntity<String> response = personService.sentFriendRequest(from, toPerson);
    if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
        try {
            NotificationMessage notification = new NotificationMessage(from, "You have a new friend request from " + from);
            System.out.println("Sending notification to: " + toPerson);
            messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(toPerson, "/queue/notifications", notification);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("something went wrong");
    }
    return response;
}

this is my frontend code foe connecting to websockets
useEffect(() => {
const client = new Client({
brokerURL: "ws://localhost:8080/ws",
reconnectDelay: 5000,
webSocketFactory: () => new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/ws"),
connectHeaders: {
Authorization: Bearer ${Bearer},
},
onConnect: () => {
console.log("Connected to WebSocket");
setIsConnected(true);
        client.subscribe("/public/notifications", (message) => {
            console.log("Received notification: " + message.body);
        });

        client.subscribe(`/user/${email}/queue/notifications`, (message) => {
            try {
                const notification = JSON.parse(message.body);
                alert(notification.message);
                console.log("Received private notification:", notification);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error("Failed to parse notification message:", e);
            }
        });
    },
    onStompError: (frame) => {
        console.error("Broker error:", frame.headers["message"]);
        setIsConnected(false); 
    },
});

client.activate();
setStompClient(client);

return () => {
    client.deactivate();
};

}, []);
<Button label="Accept" severity="info" onClick={() => handleAcceptRequest(person.email)} />
const handleAcceptRequest = (friend) => {
api
.post(/user/accept-request/${email}, null, {
headers: {
Authorization: Bearer ${Bearer},
},
params: {
from: friend,
},
})
.then((response) => {
console.log(response);
setFetchData((x) => !x);
})
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
`
how to resolve the issue for sending notification to a specific user using websockets (STOMP) I have enabled spring security in my application.`

Are you seeing any errors on the server or the client?
